# Remark inside a proof

Tags: proof-writing, article-writing

It is a good practice to define a remark **inside** the proof of a theorem to highlight a necessary observation to go on the proof?

Edit (the scheme that I imagine is the following):

$\textit{Proof }$
...
$\textit{Remark definition}$
....
end Proof

Comment: Proofs are normally stuffed with comments !?

Comment: I mean: define explicitly a Remark inside the proof.

Comment: Do you mean formal proofs?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I deal with a proof of a theorem, that is defined by steps. In one of them, I need to point out an observation that is the key to close the proof.

Comment: I think comments/remarks are good practice (like in coding), as long as the formal proof itself is self-sufficient (i.e., does not rely on them to be valid and decipherable).